# Sonata Child admin and invalid links in the tab menu

Tags: symfony, sonata

I have one admin called "User" and this has one child called "Shoes". In the "User" admin I use the method configureTabMenu in order to create a menu with the "shoes". This works well, when I click in the "Shoes" menu then the shoes admin is shown and this tab appear as active. All work fine, just the shoes menu url is not ok when i am on it

admin/shoes/list?id=2

however normally it must be

/admin/users/2/shoes/list

the last one should be the correct,

in the following file

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I find a temporary fix in sonata admin bundle 
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/2505